# Problem in configuring the WSO2 APIM Analytics with WSO2 APIM 3.0

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure the WSO2 APIM Analytics Ver 3.1 with WSO2 APIM 3.0 in distributed environment, But it is showing "No Dashboards available" in Analytics Dashboard and no error is there in logs.

I am not sure about the configuration i have done in deployment.toml. Please help me in configuring the Analytics with APIM.

Following is the configuration for auth.config in deployment.toml(dashboard):

```
auth.configs:
  type: 'apim'
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin apim_analytics:product_manager apim_analytics:api_developer apim_analytics:app_developer apim_analytics:devops_engineer apim_analytics:analytics_viewer apim_analytics:everyone openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe
    adminServiceBaseUrl: https://Publisher Server URL
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://Key-Manager Server URL/client-registration/v0.15/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://Key-Manager Server URL/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://Key-Manager Server URL/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 900
    baseUrl: https://Analytics Server URL
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://Key-Manager Server URL
    storeUrl: https://Store URL
    externalLogoutUrl: https://Key-Manager Server URL/oidc/logout
```

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/issues/812) and is fixed with the following [Pull Request](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/pull/868).

Answer (score 1):

We have already fixed this issue. Please check with the latest released [APIM Analytics 3.1.0-m4 release](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/releases/download/v3.1.0-m4/wso2am-analytics-3.1.0-m4.zip) and tell us whether this issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will explore the same and revert in case of any issue.

Comment: Hi Raveen, I have tried APIM Analytics 3.1.0 with APIM 3.0 in distributed environment with same configuration as mentioned above, but it is throwing the following error: Invalid Request
invalid_callback
Registered callback does not match with the provided url.

Comment: Log in to the carbon console(ex: https://localhost:9443/carbon) and [delete](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adding-and-configuring-a-service-provider/#deleting-service-providers) the **admin_sp_analytics_dashboard** service provider and restart the dashboard. In the latest release we have changed the callbacks. That's why you got above error.

Comment: Or else you can login to the APIM 3.0 management console and edit the callback url in the service provider as below.
regexp=(https://<analytics_node host:port>/login/callback/analytics-dashboard/login|https://<analytics_node host:port>/analytics-dashboard)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted the admin_sp_analytics_dashboard and now It is working fine..

Comment: Hi Raveen, Now Dashboard is displaying but when i am clicking on Developer Portal/Publisher it is throwing following error. I am trying to solve it for the last two days. Please confirm is it a bug or any wrong configuration. Thanks
{org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener} com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 19 column 1 path $

Comment: Can you share the full error log here? On a side note, you can subscribe to our [DEV](https://wso2.com/mail/) mailing list and ask your questions there.